# Spring Boot inbuilt Tomcat Server - what is the advantage with respect of normal Spring app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It is not clear to me, the difference between Spring Boot and normal Spring Application.

According to the documentation Spring Boot has an inbuilt Tomcat Server but what is the practical advantage of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This removes the need of having an instance of web server installed on your machine.

You simply configure all the properties of the web server inside your application.properties with `server.tomcat` prefix -> [list of properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Now you just need a machine with JVM installed on it and thats it.

This strategy also makes sure, that no matter where you start your application, the server and its configuration are the same.

Remember that you can always build your spring boot app the old way by creating a deployable WAR:

**1)** pom packaging: `<packaging>war</packaging>`

**2)** spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**3)** extend `@SpringBootApplication` class with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
```

Keeping that in mind you have to decide what is the most proper way of building and deploying your spring boot application. I had to use each of these depending on the current needs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse spring boot with spring application.

As mentioned "Spring Boot is a Spring framework module which provides RAD (Rapid Application Development) feature to the Spring framework." its more or like plug and play type.
Just do a minor setup and configuration, your application is up and running. Inbuilt tomcat help you to deploy your application, else you have to manually do a deployment.

Meaning you can make application with spring boot very fast. Spring boot helps you with this and many more.

1.To avoid complex XML configuration in Spring.

2.To develop a production ready Spring applications in an easier way.